# PHP send main answer

Tags: php, sendmail

I'm on my very first steps of php, i have send mail form, which is included to another page, so practically it's working via **index.php?email=support** And index.php gives just information.

Form is working **index.php?email=support**, once it's got sended, it's just refreshes page to **index.php** insted of **index.php?email=support** which should give answer that email is sent. As i understood it should be sent via form to page link

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="contactform">
```

Kindly help with .. i guess very simple question for some one :) So once mail is sent, page will refresh to index.php?mail=support and would give answer that email is sent.

Thank you!

Comment: What's the code of your index.php file ? (Useful parts only)

Comment: Here is copy: http://jsfiddle.net/3s4rubcm/

Comment: You should not use ```PHP_SELF``` as this is prone for cross-site-scripting. Try ```index.php?email=support&somethingelse="><b>Hello</b>"```

Comment: you mean to use "index.php?email=support" insted of "echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']"???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

only returns the script name and skips any request variables like email=support. You'll need to change the action to something like:

```
<form method="post" action="/index.php?email=support&send=1" id="contactform">
```

Based on the $_GET['send'] variable you'll be able to tell if the message was send and if the system should display a message confirming it did like so:

```
if (!empty($_GET['send']))
{
    echo 'Message successfully send!';
}
```

Comment: It already have answer: <!-- ok and error msg -->
    <?php if(isset($hasError)) { ?><p class="msg-error">check again</p><?php } ?>
    <?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) { ?><div class="msg-ok">
        <p><strong>sent</strong></p>
        <p>it's sent</p>
    </div><?php } ?>

Comment: But, what about using "PHP_SELF" Just found some info in internet tellin, it's not the best option, is it???

Comment: Okay, are you actually setting $emailSent after posting the form? If not: it will not have any effect.

Regarding your comment not to use PHP_SELF: PHP_SELF indeed leaves you vulnerable for XSS attacks. You might as well use index.php?email=support&send=1, I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yeap, looks gr8, but: <form method="post" action="/index.php?email=support&send=1" id="contactform">
Cheers!